# Mod_rewrite inclusion problem with css

Tags: php, css, mod-rewrite, radix

I new to mod_rewrite.

i have this page **profiles.php?page=XXX**

i tried to move it to more friendly url /cars/XXX/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^cars/([^/]+)/?$ profiles.php?page=$1 [L]
```

problem is when i include style

```
<link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

it doesnt work,

```
<link href="./../../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

works fine, but wont work with profile.php?carname=XXX

why is that happening ? how can i fix it

**Note:**

I have a small script that determine the base address of website by counting number of /

```
global $base_addr;
$s=substr_count($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],"/",2)-1;
$base_addr=".";
if($s > 0)$base_addr.=str_repeat("/..",$s);
require_once($base_addr.'class/xxx.php');
echo "<link href='$Base_addr/css/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />";
```

In this code require_once will works perfectly, only html hrefs is my problem any fix for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this works better.

```
<base href="/" />
```

Especially since you can define the base root of your site, then none of the assets like css or jquery in sub directories get lost.

```
<base href="www.url.org/" /> 
<base href="www.url.org/directory/" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use absolute URLs (relative to Domain's root):

```
<link href="/path/to/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

`/path/to/css/style.css` is same as `http://www.domain.com/path/to/css/style.css`

In that way it doesn't depend on the number of slashes in your URL.

Comment: well i use $base_addr for all includes even php, it works totaly fine only html includes that doesnt works.

Comment: require_once($base_addr.'class/XX.php'); works fine, what doesnt work is html hrefs ,